# How do I clean up my Jquery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently experimenting with JQuery and tried making my own portfolio that would change the project shown on click. I have a lot of duplicated code in there and want to clean it up, I know how I used to do it in Java but I forgot the name of the method.

In the end I would like to have something like this, but I forgot how to do It exactly:

```
$('.projects a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e){

        var href = $(this).attr('href');;

        changePortfolio(String head, String text, String imgsource){
                $(".description-head").html(head);
                $(".description-text").html(text);
                $('.preview').attr('src',imgsource);
        }

        if(href == "#project-portfolio"){

            changePortfolio("Portfolio", "this is my portfolio", "bg.png");

        }
```

My current code:

```
$('.projects a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e){

        var href = $(this).attr('href');;

        if(href == "#project-portfolio"){

            $(".description-head").html("PORTFOLIO WEBSITE");
            $(".description-text").html("This is the portfolio website description");
            $('.preview').attr('src','img/bg.jpg');

        } else if(href == "#project-preview2"){

            $(".description-head").html("PREVIEW 2");
            $(".description-text").html("This is the preview 2 description");
            $('.preview').attr('src','img/placeholder.jpg');

        } else if(href == "#project-preview3"){

            $(".description-head").html("PREVIEW 3");
            $(".description-text").html("This is the preview 3 description");
            $('.preview').attr('src','img/placeholder.jpg');

        } else if(href == "#project-preview4"){

            $(".description-head").html("PREVIEW 4");
            $(".description-text").html("This is the preview 4 description");
            $('.preview').attr('src','img/placeholder.jpg');

        }  else if(href == "#project-preview5"){

            $(".description-head").html("PREVIEW 5");
            $(".description-text").html("This is the preview 5 description");
            $('.preview').attr('src','img/placeholder.jpg');

        }
    });
```

Thanks for reading :)

Comment: You might want to ask questions like this on [Codereview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), which specializes on reviewing code and commenting on it.

Answer (score 2):

Consider something like this:

```
const HREF_TABLE = {
    'project-portfolio': {
        'head': "PORTFOLIO WEBSITE",
        'text': 'This is the portfolio website description',
        'preview': 'img/bg.jpg'
    },
    'project-preview2': {
        'head': "PREVIEW 2",
        'text': 'This is the preview 2 description',
        'preview': 'img/placeholder.jpg'
    }
}

$('.projects a[href^="#"]').on('click', function() {
    let href = $(this).attr('href');
    let changeTo = HREF_TABLE[href.substr(1)];

    if ( changeTo !== undefined ) {
        changePortfolio(changeTo);
    }
});
```

In my opinion, much easy to edit this instead of using the switch-case mechanism...

Answer (score 1):

Condensing the cosmetic changes into a function was the first step. The second step I would suggest is taking your long and messy `if/else`  statements and using a `switch`, like so:

```
switch (href) {
    case "#project-portfolio":
        changePortfolio(...);
        break;
    case "#project-preview2":
        changePortfolio(...);
        break;
    // correspondingly for every case
    default:
        changePortfolio(...) // whatever the 'backup' should be
                             // if none of the above cases are met
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this removed a lot of clutter in my code. I can't seem to get changePortfolio to work, do you know how to fix it or the name of programming in this style (I forgot) so I can search the web?

Comment: Maybe it's something you got from Java, but in JS you don't declare the data type of the parameters, so changing your argument list to `(head, text, imgsource)` will help.